# VBA Excel add new sheet with number based on the previous sheet created

Tags: excel, vba

I have the Sheet called "Area Map 1".
I want to create the button, which will add the new sheet for me (copy the "Area Map 1") with the name Area Map 2.
The button is going to add one sheet only. It means, that it can be used repeatedly if we need to create more sheets. However, if I use this button once, then my last existing sheet under this name is "Area Map 2". Using the button again will result from the error "The name is already taken, try the different one".

[image]

What should I improve in the code below then?

```
  Sub ConsecutiveNumberSheets()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - (Sheets.Count - 1)
  With Sheets("Area Map 1")
  .Copy after:=ActiveSheet
  ActiveSheet.Name = "Area Map " & (i + 1)
  .Select
  End With
  Next i
  End Sub
```

I want something, which will detect, that the new sheet with incremented numbers is already created. What should I do to base my code on the last number of the already existing sheets?

Comment: Why are you looping through all sheets if you just want to add one?

Comment: Might a previous copy have been deleted before you create another?  So you might have map1 and Map 3 but Map 2 was deleted, then you want another copy - should it be Map 4 or Map 2 ?

Comment: @SJR this is one of the way. I don't knowyet how to add one sheet simplyso I used the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add Incremented Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createIncrementedWorksheet()
    
    Const wsPattern As String = "Area Map "
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim arr() As Long: ReDim arr(1 To wb.Sheets.Count)
    Dim wsLen As Long: wsLen = Len(wsPattern)
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim shName As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        shName = sh.Name
        If StrComp(Left(shName, wsLen), wsPattern, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            cValue = Right(shName, Len(shName) - wsLen)
            If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                n = n + 1
                arr(n) = CLng(cValue)
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
    If n = 0 Then
        n = 1
    Else
        ' If you just want the number to be one greater then the greatest,
        ' you can use the one liner...
        'n = Application.Max(arr) + 1
        ' ... instead of the following before 'End If':
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To n)
        For n = 1 To n
            If IsError(Application.Match(n, arr, 0)) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
    End If
            
    Set sh = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    sh.Name = wsPattern & CStr(n)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how to instead of adding new, just copy the existing sheet? They closed my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152671/vba-excel-copy-sheet-with-number-based-on-the-previous-sheet-copied

Comment: @VBasic2008 why did you add this to an array?

Comment: I have two questions: 1. Let's say that `"Area Map X"` is a worksheet and I will only use `X` in the following. If e.g. you have `1,2,3` and you delete `2`, then you have `1,3`. When you add another, should it be `2` or `4`? 2. Again you have `1,2,3`. What exactly do you want to copy (*existing sheet!?*) and increment? - The array only helps me to find the next available number.

Answer (score 1):

this should do what you're looking for.

```
Public Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startName As String: startName = "Area Map "
    Dim counter As Integer: counter = 1
    
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets                      
        If Left(ws.Name, Len(startName)) = startName Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If            
    Next ws
    
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add
    startName = startName & counter
    ws.Name = startName
End Sub
```

Comment: The debuggers says: startName not definied

Comment: OK sorted. It was Dim startNmae instead of startName

Comment: I have fixed it. sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me what should I change in this code in order to copy the existing sheet instead of creating the new one? They've closed my new query regarding this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152671/vba-excel-copy-sheet-with-number-based-on-the-previous-sheet-copied