# VBA Excel, copied sheets come in wrong order

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with the problem. I have two sheets with a different name and I want them copied throughout the document on the same basis as explained in the queries below:

[VBA Excel add new sheet with number based on the previous sheet created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142013/vba-excel-add-new-sheet-with-number-based-on-the-previous-sheet-created)

[VBA Excel duplicate the existing sheet with number based on the previous sheet duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158094/vba-excel-duplicate-the-existing-sheet-with-number-based-on-the-previous-sheet-d/66171991#66171991)

Whereas the 1 sheet name works fine, the error occurs when launching 2 of them simultaneously.

My code looks as follows:

```
 Sub Sheetaadding()

 'first sheet

 Dim wsr As Worksheet, wso As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set wsr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vet Area Map 1")
 Set wso = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Area Map 1 Open")
 Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
 Dim xCount As Integer, yCount As Integer

 For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If InStr(1, Sheets(I).Name, "Vet") > 0 Then xCount = xCount + 1
 Next

 For I = 1 To Sheets.Count - (Sheets.Count - 1)

 With Sheets("Vet Area Map 1")
 .Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index + xCount + I)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "Vet Area Map " & xCount + 1
.Select
End With
Next I

'second sheet

For J = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If InStr(1, Sheets(J).Name, "Open") > 0 Then yCount = yCount + 1
Next

For J = 1 To Sheets.Count - (Sheets.Count - 1)

 With Sheets("Area Map 1 Open")
 .Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wso.Index + (yCount + (J - 1)))
 ActiveSheet.Name = "Area Map " & yCount + 1 & " Open"
.Select
End With
Next J

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And the result is quite opposite. Since the Vet Area Map comes fine, the Area Map 1 Open comes in opposite order.
[image]

How can I make these sheets appearing interchangeably as shown in the image ("Desired order"). I want to appear Vet Area Map3, Area Map 3 Open, Vet Area Map 4, Area Map 4 Open and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I missed something, but I think the convoluted `.Copy After:=` is the source of the problem.

I'm also not sure what the loops are for, but `For I = 1 To Sheets.Count - (Sheets.Count - 1)` is the same as `I = 1 to x - (x-1)` Which is the same as `I = 1 to 1`, so not much of a loop.

Technically, unless you are going to delete pages, there seems to be little use to count twice, neither is selecting the original sheet after each action. And some other cleaning:

```
Sub Sheetaadding()

Dim wsr As Worksheet, wso As Worksheet
Dim I As Long, xCount As Long
Set wsr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vet Area Map 1")
Set wso = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Area Map 1 Open")

For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If InStr(1, Sheets(I).Name, "Vet") > 0 Then xCount = xCount + 1
Next

 'first sheet
wsr.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index - 1 + xCount * 2)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Vet Area Map " & xCount + 1

'second sheet
wso.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Area Map " & xCount + 1 & " Open"


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it's fine but I need them after the activesheets, something like:
.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index + xCount + I)

Comment: What do you mean after the activesheets? Are you going to have other sheets after these sheets, and then add these in between?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I need the order you solved for me, but not at the Sheets.count but after the "Area Map" & xCount + 1 & " Open" sheet.

Comment: Or do you mean that the order you want is: vet 1 | open 1 | vet 2,3,4,5... | open 2,3,4,5....

Comment: No, my order must be Vet1/open1/vet2/open2/vet3/open3 and so on, and next other sheets remaining

Comment: That's absolutely perfect! However I don't understand xCount *2, what does this *2 mean here?  In my case I altered the code to Count *2+5 and Count*2 + 6.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't account for it to not be the first Sheet. I updated with a more variable approach. `wsr.Index - 1` adds whatever amount of sheets befor "Vet1". Then `xCount * 2` will point to the last "open"-sheet, thus adding after that one. `*2` since we add two sheets each time. Say that we are on xCount = 3, then we have `xCount * 2` sheets, that is 6 sheets. So Vet 4 will be added after the 6th sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I wasn't aware of this *2 so I was wandering aimlessly for a few hours.